# Suppress external command error output from Powershell $error

Tags: powershell

In my profile, I've customised the prompt via the `prompt` function to embed git branch information:

```
function prompt
{
    $prefix = ""
    if ((test-path ".git") -or (test-path ".gitdir") -or ((git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null) -eq "true")) {
        $prefix = "[git:" + (& git symbolic-ref --short HEAD) + "]"
    }

    write-host "PS $prefix $(get-location) >" -nonewline -foregroundcolor DarkMagenta
    return " "
}
```

The problem however is that when I'm outside of a git tree, the `git rev-parse` part of the check inserts an error into `$error` even though I'm redirecting errors to $null.

This means that $error gets polluted with the following error, as it is generated every time the prompt renders:

```
git : fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
At C:\temp\prompt.ps1:4 char:64
    + ... ".gitdir") -or ((git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null) -eq "t ...
    +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Not a gi...ectories): .git:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Running interactively I've noticed that the `2> $null` does suppress the error to the console, but the error still appears in $error:

```
PS C:\temp> $error
PS C:\temp> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null
PS C:\temp> $error
git : fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
At line:1 char:1
+ git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Not a gi...ectories): .git:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS C:\temp>
```

I've tried wrapping the command in `try {...} catch {}`, and also using `invoke-command` with an erroraction of ignore, both with no luck:

```
PS c:\temp> $error.clear()
PS c:\temp> $error
PS c:\temp> invoke-command -scriptblock { git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null } -erroraction ignore
PS c:\temp> $error
git : fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
At line:1 char:31
+ ... d -scriptblock { git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null } -erro ...
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Not a gi...ectories): .git:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS c:\temp> $error.clear()
PS c:\temp> $error
PS c:\temp> try { git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null } catch { }
PS c:\temp> $error
git : fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
At line:1 char:7
+ try { git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2> $null } catch { }
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: Not a gi...ectories): .git:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

PS c:\temp>
```

How can I suppress this error from adding to `$error` so it stays clean?

Comment: if you change `2> $Null` to `2>$Null` it seems to work for me. note the _removal_ of the space between the `>` and the `$`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - removing the space hasn't worked for me, unfortunately.

Comment: well, now the space makes no difference. [*blush*] i don't know what i was doing earlier that made it _seem_ to work differently. ///// however, when i use your code [`git rev-parse --is-inside-worktree 2> $Null`] on my `win7, ps5.1, git version 2.21.0.windows.1` setup, the error is suppressed.

Comment: I'm on Win10, PS 5.1, git 2.11.1.windows.1

Comment: perhaps it would help to upgrade your git-for-windows installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell Core 6.2.1 / Windows PowerShell v5.1, using `2>$null` to suppress stderr output from an external program unexpectedly still takes a detour via Powershell's error stream (stream  `2`), so the output is still recorded in `$Error`. This known problem is described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4572).

As a workaround, you can call `git` via `cmd /c` (or `sh -c` on Unix) and let *it* do the redirection:

```
# Windows
cmd /c 'git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>NUL'

# Linux, macOS
sh -c 'git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null'
```

As you state, this will correctly pass `git`'s exit code through so you can determine success via `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards.

Comment: Excellent - ta. Also happy to see that cmd propagates the truthy success so working nicely in an if.